# Addable edit text android material d

Tags: java, android, components

I was looking for an answer how to let user add more text field depending on his request... As i guess it comes from some kind of list but how to earn similary to this below efect ? [addable edit text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347uZ.png)

My target is to create some kind of a formula where user adds his ingredients and their amount, everything has it's own Type like chicken is a meat, potatoe is a vegetable etc.
I want to make it a part of a material design project so it should fits to it.
I dont request for a full code answer(what would be great anyway, i try to learn it in the best way), even a tip is significant for me.
Thx for help :)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how many items can be added, a ListView or probably better a RecyclerView (better/easier for animations than ListView) might be ideal. However, if you only see a user having between 1 - 20ish ingredients an easy approach might be just to dynamically inflate items.

When the "Add" button is pressed, use LayoutInflater to inflate a new view which represents the ingredient and then add it to the parent. In your layout xml, add `android:animateLayoutChanges="true"` to your parent layout. Now, when the new ingredient is added it will do a nice insert animation. It will also create a nice animation when you remove a child from the parent.

This [Android Developer Article](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html) might be helpful too.

Comment: That's it what i've needed, Thx a lot :)!